# What do you call the mimicking of music and sounds through whistling?

Tags: terminology, pitch

I recently realised that I can repeat sounds I hear by whistling. Not all sounds, some fall out my whistling range, but I can whistle any music I know. What is this phenomenon called? I don't think it is perfect pitch because I don't know the names of notes.

I think I'm going to practice my whistling by trying to expand my range and get my whistling to become more musical, maybe I should consider becoming a concert whistler. I don't know, mimicking sounds and music I hear by whistling is just something I have done my whole life.

Comment: It's just called 'whistling'. Most people can do it, just as they can sing anything they know.

Comment: Ummm... I think that's just called "whistling". [Obligatory reference.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8W3puhJiGGE)

Comment: It's literally just called "whistling".

Comment: You can whistle the *pitches* you hear, but I doubt you can whistle the *sounds*. Oboe, sax, violin, guitar, piano, harp...? The list goes on... Vtc rather than dv. Phenomenon, also., not phenomena (plural).

Comment: Ok, the term I was searching for was echolalia. I often repeat accents and sounds I find interesting some trough whistling..

Comment: Echolalia is an automatic tic where one repeats the last words of everything that someone else has just said, which happens regardless of whether it was interesting. It has nothing to do with deliberate mimicking of sounds you like.

Answer (score 2):

It's called 'being able to whistle'.   A posh name for someone who has this skill is 'siffleur'.

Not to be confused with this gentleman:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_P%C3%A9tomane

Comment: 'It's an ill wind...'